# Merge columns to create new records - mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, merge, multiple-columns

I have a mysql database and I need to merge two columns together, however I need to merge the columns in such a way that they are not just concatenated together but instead a whole new separate record.

Example:

```
Before Merge:
name    Computer-one     Computer-two
jack       hp                  dell

<insert unkown sql statement (what I need)>

After Merge
name    Computer-one
jack       hp               
jack       dell
```

When I try to merge the two columns they simply merge in to a single column but do not repeat the record instead (look above):

```
name    Computer-one     
jack       hpdell
```

Currently I am using the `concat` statement.  Which is the only way I've been able to get the items to merge.  These columns can contain null values, there is a ID that auto increments for the primary key.

Comment: How do you want to identify 'jack'? Is this dynamic or a parameter you want to pass to your query? The solution you need is query computer-one separately the do a union with computer-two firall records belonging to the name

Comment: @Julius A there could be several different names in this database so probably dynamic.  For the record creating a new table and merging them like that is an acceptable answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you actually dont want to merge them.
You want to create new rows for a field.

You can just do this.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(name, Computer-one)
SELECT 
   name, Computer-two
FROM 
   table_name;
```

Then you will create new rows for all rows with there Computer-two values put into the Computer-one field.
When you see that your table has twice as many rows and the Computer-one field is correct you can just drop the 'Computer-two' column and the data is as you wanted.

Always make a backup first or try on test-tables so that you know that everything works first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need UNION ALL statement. You may try below -

```
SELECT name, "Computer-one"
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE "Computer-one" IS NOT NULL
 UNION ALL
SELECT name, "Computer-two"
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE "Computer-two" IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do two  queries on this table and union the result. Insert results into temp table. Then select distinct records for each record for column 'nane'

```
SELECT INTO table2(name, model)
SELECT A.name, A.computer-one AS model from table as A
UNION
SELECT B.name, B.computer-two AS model from table as B
```